# Código para refrescar una MSFlexGrid no lo hace y además elimina las cabeceras

Tags: vb6

tengo este código en VB6 para refrescar una MSFlexGrid, pero no lo refresca y además me elimina las cabeceras

```vb
 If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
    rs.Close
 End If
 MSFlexGridfacturacioncontrolcobro.Redraw = False
 Dim sRuta As String
 ' Abre una nueva conexión ADO
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 sRuta = "C:\PsGranadaVB6V1\BasesDatosActual\PsGranadaVb6.mdb"
 ' Cadena de conexión
 cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & sRuta & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False"
 'Abre la conexión
 cn.Open
 ' nuevo recordset
 'Si la propiedad CursorLocation se establece en adUseClient, la única configuración válida para la propiedad CursorType es adOpenStatic.
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
 miSQL = "SELECT IdSocioCC , NombreSocioCC, TipoSocioCC, CajaBancoCC, EneCC, FebCC, MarCC, AbrCC, MayCC, JunCC, JulCC, AgoCC, SetCC," _
 & "OctCC, NovCC, DicCC, InsCC , ExtCC, EspCC, JuvCC, InfCC, ActivoBajaCC, TotalCobradoCC, TotalPendienteCC, TotalPeriodoCC" _
 & " FROM SociosControlCobro WHERE TipoSocioCC = '" & "INF" & "'" & " And ActivoBajaCC = '" & "ACTIVO" & "' ORDER BY IdSocioCC;"      
 rs.Open miSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
 ' rellena la grilla con los datos del recordset. Le pasa el número o index del campo que actuará como CheckBox
 Call Cargar_FlexGrid(MSFlexGridfacturacioncontrolcobro, 0, rs)
 Label4.Visible = True: OptionfacturSI.Visible = True: OptionfacturNO.Visible = True: Label5.Visible = False
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set cn = Nothing
 MSFlexGridfacturacioncontrolcobro.Redraw = True
```